# Handling large amount of missing values in categorical variables.

Tags: classification, categorical-data, missing-data

I have a binary Classification problem and I have a dataset with lot of categorical variables and many of them have missing information. I proceeded with dropping all the missing values from the dataset and lost many rows of data.

Should I take another level(category) for the missing values and put it in the model.
But I am not sure if they all are missing due to similar particular condition.
What should be done in these scenarios?

Comment: You could also look into imputation, search this site!

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly reasonable to add "not available" category. If you have different causes of nonavailability, you can create different categories for that as well. But make sure that that causes influence your target class, otherwise "not available" will be enough.